# Display properties of an XML file using XmlTextWriter

Tags: c#

I have created an xml file using the following code:

```
XmlTextWriter write = new XmlTextWriter(FileName, null);

write.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
write.WriteStartDocument();
write.WriteComment("Its Xml Document");

write.WriteStartElement("CollegeInformation");
write.WriteStartElement("StudentDetails");

write.WriteElementString("stdID", "1001");  
write.WriteElementString("StudentName", "XYZ");

write.WriteEndElement();
write.WriteEndElement();
write.WriteEndDocument();

write.Close();
```

Now I want to display the properties of this xml file like `name`, `file` `size`, `length` on console.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Did You save this file anywhere ? If You want to get filename or filesize use clas FileInfo of System.IO namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Use can use FileInfo class to get the file properties.

```
System.IO.FileInfo f = new System.IO.FileInfo(FileName);
Console.WriteLine("The size of {0} is {1} bytes.", f.Name, f.Length);
```

Click on below link to get the properties available with the FileInfo Class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx